# Show that $\varphi:\mathbb{R}→Gl_2 (\mathbb{R})$ defined by $\varphi(a)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ is not an isomorphism

Tags: matrices, group-theory, group-isomorphism

$\varphi:\mathbb{R}→Gl_2 (\mathbb{R})$  defined by the matrix  $\varphi(a)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

An isomorphism is a homomorphism that is also bijective.  $\varphi(a)$ is a homomorphism so in order to show it is not an isomorphism I must show it is not 1 to 1 or onto or that it does not have a 2 sided inverse. I am not sure how to show these things. Any help?

Comment: 35 days a member + 10 questions asked = learn how to properly type mathematics in this site, lest your post won't even be read by many: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Have you thought about which condition it might fail? If you make an educated guess as to which criteria might fail, it might help point you in the right direction. In addition it shows us that you've given the problem some thought and are truly stuck on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $A:=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$; then $A\in GL_2(\Bbb R)$ but $\varphi(a)\neq A$ for every $a\in\Bbb R$, thus $\varphi$ is NOT surjective, and in particular it cannot be an isomorphism.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: To show $\varphi$ is not onto, you just have to find a single element of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ that does not have the form $\begin{pmatrix}1 & a \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$.  Can you find an invertible $2\times 2$ matrix that doesn't look like that?